# Most efficient way to get current word from char array

Tags: c, optimization, string-search

Say I have a string "text", a caret position "caret" and then want to find the current word (seperated by space).

The way I'm currently doing it seems inefficient and I was wondering if anyone had a efficient way of doing it?

```
const char* text;
int caret;
int initpos;
int start;
int count = 0;
char word[256];

// text and caret values assigned here.

initpos = caret;
while(caret > 0 && text[caret] != ' ') // get start
{
    caret--;
    count++;
}
start = caret;
caret = initpos;

while(text[caret] && text[caret] != ' ') // get end
{
    caret++;
    count++;
}

word = strsub(text, start, count);
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile, you can't assign to word which is an array name.

Comment: It would seem to me hard to beat this code (assuming @unwind's comment, and the uninitialized `caret`, and walking right off your array bounds are just instances of trying to trim the problem down to something that can be easily posted and discussed) -- you've got to look at every character before and after, and finding a trick to find a space faster than individual character inspection seems unlikely.

Comment: Maybe you want to also consider horizontal tabs etc. in addition to spaces.

Comment: You don't really need the variable `count` and you might make it a little faster using pointer arithmetic instead of array indexing, but unless you're working with very long words or a large part of the overall execution time is in this part of the code, I doubt you'd notice the difference...

Comment: @jswolf19: turning compiler optimization on may do exactly that.

Comment: What do you want to happen if `caret` points to a space? The way your code is now, it will try `strsub(text, start, 0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By "seems inefficient", do you mean the code **looks** inefficient to you or that you've **measured** and found it too slow for you purposes?

Your method takes O(*n*) steps where *n* is the length of the longest word in your input. That's pretty fast unless your words have the size of DNA strings.

A faster method, for some datasets, would be to use an index of word start and end positions. An binary search tree storing intervals would fit this bill, but at the expense of O(lg *N*) retrieval time, where *N* is the number of words in your input. Probably not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is an efficient approach. I would just suggest checking if the character is a letter, rather than if it is not a space:

```
while(caret > 0 && ((text[caret]>='A' && text[caret]<='Z') || (text[caret]>='a' && text[caret]<='z')))
```

This will catch other cases, e.g. when word is terminated by a dot, a digit, a bracket etc.

Comment: Why not `isalpha()` (declared in `<ctype.h>`) instead? Your condition won't "catch" `ã` or `ÿ` or many other word-forming characters, while `isalpha()`, with the proper locale set, catches all word characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <ctype.h>

...
// Other definitions from above.
char *p = word;
char *q = text + caret;
while(q >= text && !isblank(*q)) {
   q--;
}
if (q < text) q++; // All non-blanks.
while (*q && !isblank(*q)) {
   *p++ = *q++;
}
*p = '\0';
// word now has nul terminated non-blank characters, p points to EOL or blanks.
```

Comment: I don't think this is the same as the sample code provided: it won't look "backwards" to find the start of the word. To see more what the original poster wanted, start `vim`, enter visual selection mode with `v`, and use `aW` to select "a WORD". No matter where you place the cursor in the word, the entire word will be selected.

Comment: @sarnold: You're right. I need more coffee. You'd have to initially walk backwatds looking for a blank or the beginning of the string.